# How to cancel task run by click on another cancel button in c#?

Tags: c#, undo, cancellation, request-cancelling

I have a scenario like a user is sending mail and want's to cancel that action in a particular time limit.
If the user clicks the cancel button in 5 second user can cancel that action and send mail should be aborted.

It's almost similar functionality of Gmail undo email sending.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far so we can try to help you

Comment: You can cancel the task if the email send still pending.
If you want to cancel an already sent email you'll have to check with your SMTP server if it's possible...

Maybe the best should be to hold the launch request during 5 seconds and only after that send it ? In that case you can cancel it before sending it to the SMTP server.

Comment: I am looking for what option is available to cancel task, i understood it is possible with CancellationTokenSource() in c#. Now i have to try with it. Am i on right track or any better option?